# Проблема со встраиванием в Webview видео с vimeo (embed)

Tags: java, android, android-webview, vimeo

В приложении нужно реализовать воспроизведение видео с youtube и vimeo, для решения этого вопроса был выбран `Webview` и [вот этот пример](https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView/tree/master/app/src/main/java/name/cpr). С youtube всё отрабатывает отлично(полноэкранный режим в том числе). А вот с vimeo возникли проблемы, кнопка `Play` одновременно срабатывает как `Fullscreen`.
Переход в полноэкранный режим, как я понимаю, происходит при помощи `@Override` метода `onShowCustomView/onHideCustomView` в [классе](https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/name/cpr/VideoEnabledWebChromeClient.java).

Как сделать так, чтобы кнопка `Play` выполняла только свою функцию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что мобильная версия vimeo всегда открывается в полный экран при начале воспроизведения, даже если используется в `Embed`. Решил проблему так: просто изменил `User Agent` у `WebView` на десктопный, и всё заработало как надо.
Вот пример кода:

```
String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0"; 
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
```